# Reading csv without specifying enclosure characters in Weka

Tags: csv, converters, weka, loader, reader

I have a dataset that I want to open in Weka, so I converted it as csv file. (The file contains some text including commas/apostrophes/quotation marks, while its seperator is pipeline character.)

When I try to read this csv file, in options window, I specify pipeline (|) as my *fieldSeperator*, leave *enclosureCharacters* empty, and don't touch the rest of the options. This can be seen in the screenshot:

[image: ss1]

Then  I get this error:
[image: ss2]

> File not recognised as an 'CSV data files' file. Reason: Enclosures
>   can only be single characters.

Seems like Weka's csv loader does not accept *enclosureCharacters* field empty? What can I write into this field? I think my file does not have enclosures for its text data.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a dummy character in *enclosureCharacters* i.e. a character that isn't present in your file?

Comment: @nekomatic While waiting answer from stackoverflow, I did a similar approach to be able to load my dataset, so I can start practicing weka functions. But still, I don't understand the assumption, why every file must have enclosure characters.. :(

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: To find out *why* Weka works this way you would have to either inspect the source code, or contact the authors via the [Weka mailing list](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist) and find out if it's intentional or if they consider it a bug. Maybe nobody has complained before! Meanwhile your question is arguably not really about programming, but I doubt anyone will object if you leave it up.

Comment: @nekomatic You're right, thanks. And sorry, my search in StackExchange directed me to StackOverflow, all other weka related questions were in StackOverflow.